# More space charactesr in sequence in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to add 3-5 spaces between two words in `Label` but what is effectively seen is only one.

```
getToolBar().setLabelText( "WordA        WordB");
```

result is:

```
WordA WordB
```

Is there a simple way hot to achieve this without using 2 `Label`s? I tried insert `&nbsp` but it did not work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a Label you can use a HTML widget (extends Label). You can then use the `setHTML()` method to set the inner html, which can include `&nbsp;` or any other valid html.